# Oracle PL/SQL table of parent object type breaks when I add another inheriting child object type

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types, object-type

I am using custom object types with Oracle PL/SQL, including several object types that inherit from a parent object.  I have a TP_DOCUMENTS parent object, and child document types, such as TP_PUBLICATION, TP_CONTRACT, etc.  We successfully created a table of TP_DOCUMENT and have added records of TP_PUBLICATION, TP_CONTRACT, and other child document records.  However, I needed to create an additional type of document.  Once I did this, it broke the DOCUMENTS table.  How can I create additional child types, without breaking the table of the parent object (making me lose all the data previously contained in the parent object table!!)?

Here is some of my code:

```
create or replace TYPE           "TP_DOCUMENT" AS OBJECT 
( 
...fields go here
) NOT FINAL

create or replace TYPE           "TP_PUB_INSTRUCTION" UNDER TP_DOCUMENT()

CREATE TABLE DOCUMENTS OF TP_DOCUMENT
```

After creating these types (and others with additional fields), I created the table DOCUMENTs as shown above.  I tried to create another sub-type, and the DOCUMENTS table broke.

MORE INFORMATION:

The error code message is as follows:

ORA-04063:  table/view has errors

```
Cause:  Attempt to execute a stored procedure or use a view that has errors.  For stored procedures, the problem could be syntax errors or references to other, non-existent procedures.    For views,  the problem could be a reference in the view's defining query to a non-existent table.  Can also be a table which has references to non-existent or inaccessible types.   

Action: Fix the errors and/or create referenced objects as necessary.
```

Thank you!

UPDATE WITH ANSWER FROM COMMENTER BELOW:

I had unfortunately dropped a Sub-Type using the Force option.  That likely was the cause for why my Documents table was corrupted.  In the future, I will use the Validate command (see answer below).

Comment: What does 'broke' mean? What did you try and what error did you get? Or if not an error, what did you see, and what did you expect to see? It truncated the table? I can't immediately recreate what I think you're saying is happening.

Comment: Hi Alex - sorry for not giving enough information.  I posted the error up above.  I cannot view any data or select it using a SQL query.  I checked all of the dependencies, removed all calls to the table, etc. with no success.

Comment: I reproduced this error when deleted one of sub-types with force option.

Comment: Was your new subtype created successfully, or did it perhaps have compilation errors? Check for any invalid objects in `all_objects`, and look for errors in `all_errors` (or `user_errors`). Were there any steps you haven't mentioned, like dropping and recreating the new subtype?

Comment: After the error occurred, I backed up my sub-types, parent type, all packages that referred to it, etc.  I deleted them all, including the documents table.  I then created the TP_Document object, all the sub-types, the document table, and all associated packages.  It worked then, as long as I created all the subtypes prior to creating the documents table.  I tried after that to create an additional sub-type, and the same error occurred once I tried to view the table.  I'll run the all_objects, and all_errors / user_errors to find out more.

Comment: This is strange - I tried it one more time (with the exact steps I just listed above).  It worked this time though.  Not sure what the difference is.  I'll still check the error tables though to see what was causing the problem earlier.

Comment: @PonderStibbons - I believe I did do that with an extra sub-type that I did not need; I forgot about that step.  Is that a typical result of deleting a sub-type with Force?  I didn't have any records of that type already in the database table, so I didn't think that would cause any issues.

Comment: You should have `ORA-02303: cannot drop or replace a type with type or table dependents` when you tried without `force`. If so, then do not drop with `force` or at least make copy of data. At least we know probable culprit.

Comment: True...thank you for catching that for me.  I'll make sure not to do that without making a copy of data if absolutely necessary to do the force.  I appreciate your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `FORCE` you should use the [`VALIDATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9006.htm#SQLRF01809) option when dropping types:

> VALIDATE
>
> If you specify VALIDATE when dropping a type, then Oracle Database
>   checks for stored instances of this type within substitutable columns
>   of any of its supertypes. If no such instances are found, then the
>   database completes the drop operation.
>
> This clause is meaningful only for subtypes. Oracle recommends the use
>   of this option to safely drop subtypes that do not have any explicit
>   type or table dependencies.

Here's an example:

```
create or replace type tp_document as object 
( 
    a number
) not final;

create or replace type tp_pub_instruction under tp_document();

create table documents of tp_document;

--This fails with this error message:
--ORA-02303: cannot drop or replace a type with type or table dependents
drop type tp_pub_instruction;

--This works since there's no data with that type.
drop type tp_pub_instruction validate;
```